# Could not find androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:27.0.2

Tags: android, flutter, geolocation, flutter-dependencies

I added geolocator dependency and then I get an error of android x incompatibility. can any help me to get out of this?

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:27.0.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/C:/Users/Rutvik/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/androidx/legacy/legacy-support-v4/27.0.2/legacy-support-v4-27.0.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :image_picker

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 7s
****************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

Migrating all the dependancies to andriodx packages will resolve this issue. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Here your geo-locator latest uses androidx packages where image_picker dependency uses android package. You need to update image_picker library to latest https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker#-changelog-tab-

or

Quick fix: Downgrade geo-locator to 2.1.1 to resolve this issue. This is not a best approach.

Upgrading all the dependancies to androidx compatable is best approach you can try.

Comment: Did you try upgrading to androidx?